# How to send websocket message via already established Websocket connection?

Tags: javascript, firefox, websocket

I am using Firefox to interact with simple websocket server. Once I open the webpage, Firefox establishes connection to websocket server.

In this situation I wish to be able to send messages using this opened connection. How can I do it? Can I use Firefox console and re-use websocket object to send a message to the server?

By default I would need to do the following:

```
let socket = new WebSocket("wss://javascript.info/article/websocket/demo/hello");

socket.onopen = function(e) {
  alert("[open] Connection established");
  alert("Sending to server");
  socket.send("My name is John");
};
```

But above code will just create new connection. My goal is to **reuse** already established connection to send messages. Any advices?

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the socket you can send as many messages as you want:

```js
let socket = new WebSocket("wss://javascript.info/article/websocket/demo/hello");

socket.onopen = function(e) {
    console.log("[open] Connection established");
    console.log("Sending to server");
    socket.send("My name is John");
};

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', e => {
    console.log("Sending to server");
    socket.send('I use the already established connection');
});
```

```html
<button>click me to send a message</button>
```

Comment: the problem here is: i dont want to create new websocket connection. Upon connecting to webpage, Websocket is created automatically and I want to reuse this one to send messages, not to have 2 websockets active.

Comment: you have a reference to the existing websocket?

Comment: then you need to provide us with more information if you dont mind